How to build an APEX
I want to eventually create some native libraries and applications. Right now I just want to try and create an APEX module with just a configuratin file or data file in it and see how it shows up on the device. I know my way around Linux hosts but not Android or soong.
From poking around using adb shell, it seems that an APEX is just a zip file with specific files in them. According to this page's File Format section https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/apex there is essentially some identification files and an apex_payload.img file. The apex_payload.img file is an ext4 disk image. The apex zip file leverages zip's capability to compress each file independently. The apex_payload.img file is not compressed at all. The apexd daemon leverages the loop devices offset and setlimit capabilities and associates a loop device with the APEX file using the offset of where the apex_payload.img file starts within the zip file and the size of the apex_payload.img file as the setlimit value for the loop device. The apexd then mounts this loop device to a directory, or assigns it to a dm device in the filesystem effectively mounting the apex_payload.img file to a directory. This makes the files inside the apex_payload.img file available to the system.
I was able to build the Android source by following the instructions at this site https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building. After the build I see a lot of files ending in apex. So, I assume the build created these. One of the pages referred to this script https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/apex/+/refs/heads/master/tools/create_apex_skeleton.sh. The script creates a directory with these files:
$ ls
Android.bp                com.bitfi.test.pem  com.bitfi.test.x509.pem  manifest.json
com.bitfi.test.avbpubkey  com.bitfi.test.pk8  file_contexts
What I am not exactly sure about is how to use this generated data. I also don't know how to get an apex_payload.img file associated with these files all bundled into a zip file with appropriate compression options for the files.
My question is how do I create an APEX zip file from this with just a simple img file that has just a simple file in it for now ?
Any pointers to step by step instructions would be helpful. I would like to add this to the build system if possible rather then trying to do something outside the build system. Any books that have step by step instructions on how to add native libraries and commands into an APEX would be great. I think I am still missing some basic concepts and books tend to provide those basic concepts pretty good.
A secondary issue is the APEX File Format page above says an APEX file should contain 4 files:
apex_manifest.json
AndroidManifest.xml
apex_pubkey
apex_payload.img

But when I look at the files on the device it shows the following content:
# zipinfo /system/apex/com.android.i18n.apex
Archive:  /system/apex/com.android.i18n.apex
Zip file size: 40353792 bytes, number of entries: 10
-rw----     2.0 fat      644 bX defN 2009-01-01 00:00 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
-rw----     2.0 fat     1104 bX defN 2009-01-01 00:00 AndroidManifest.xml
-rw----     1.0 fat       40 bx stor 2009-01-01 00:00 resources.arsc
-rw----     2.0 fat     1032 bX defN 2009-01-01 00:00 apex_pubkey
-rw----     2.0 fat      779 bX defN 2009-01-01 00:00 META-INF/CERT.SF
-rw----     2.0 fat     2063 bX defN 2009-01-01 00:00 META-INF/CERT.RSA
-rw-r--r--  1.0 unx 40226816 bx stor 2009-01-01 00:00 apex_payload.img
-rw----     1.0 fat    88984 bx stor 2009-01-01 00:00 assets/NOTICE.html.gz
-rw----     2.0 fat      151 bX defN 2009-01-01 00:00 apex_manifest.pb
-rw----     2.0 fat     1240 bX defN 2009-01-01 00:00 apex_build_info.pb
10 files, 40322853 bytes uncompressed, 40320642 bytes compressed:  0.0%

It's a head scratcher why there is no json file and a bunch of other files. Maybe the File Format page is out of date?
Any pointers would be helpful.
Thanks
